# Difference between $\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$ and $-|\omega^2|\vec{r}$ in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I am a new user in the Physics Exchange and I am currently studying rotational dynamics.

So I am encountering a problem where it is stated that $\vec{\omega}=-6\vec{i}+4\vec{j}+12\vec{k}$ with $|\omega|=14$ and $r=0.3\vec{i}-0.4\vec{j}$.

I know that there are two formulas to express the normal acceleration, namely
$$\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$$
and
$$-|\omega|^2\vec{r}$$

However, when I use the two formulas, I get different answers. Using the first formula involving cross products, I get $\vec{a_{n}}=4.8\vec{i}+3.6\vec{j}+1.2\vec{k}$ while the second formula gives me $\vec{a_{n}}=-58.5\vec{i}+78.4\vec{j}$.

**So my question is**: Why is there a difference when using $\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$ versus $-|\omega|^2\vec{r}$ in circular motion?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: If you got $4.8\vec{i}+3.6\vec{j}+1.2\vec{k}$ you mistakenly calculated $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ rather than $\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$. (But neither is equal to $-|\vec\omega|^2\vec r$.)

Comment: I get a different cross product result than you, but your two formulas in general are not equal.  Look up the $A\times (B\times C)$ identity.

Comment: I think divide first equation by sine of $\vec\omega\times \vec r$ and then again divide by sine of $\vec\omega\times\vec\omega\times \vec r$. Or you can add $\tau\hat n=\frac{d\vec B}{ds}$

Comment: @VincentThacker Thank you for the info, I will check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **So my question is**: Why is there a difference when using $\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$ versus $-|\omega|^2\vec{r}$ in circular motion?

There is a difference because they are different.

The difference is literally: $(\vec \omega \cdot \vec r)\vec \omega$.

In other words:
$$
\vec \omega \times(\vec \omega \times \vec r) = (\vec \omega \cdot \vec r)\vec \omega - |\omega|^2\vec r
$$

Therefore, these two things ($\vec \omega \times(\vec \omega \times \vec r)$ and $- |\omega|^2\vec r$) are only the same when
$(\vec \omega \cdot \vec r)\vec \omega = 0$. So, assuming $\vec \omega \neq 0$, this means that you need to have $\vec \omega \cdot \vec r=0$ for there to be no difference between the two. I.e., if $\vec \omega$ and $\vec r$ are orthogonal then the two quantities are the same, otherwise they are not the same.

In your case $\vec \omega \cdot \vec r = -0.2 \neq 0$, so the two quantities are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Difference between $\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})$ and $-|\omega^2|\vec{r}$ in circular motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/740168/difference-between-vec-omega-times-vec-omega-times-vecr-and-omega). In a three-dimensional rotational reference frame, with the object of concern being off of the equatorial axis, the centripetal force is toward the axis of rotation rather than toward the origin.  The first equation allows for this.  The second equation is only for an object on the equator, or for a two-dimensional rotating reference frame, thus making the centripetal force toward the origin.

Comment: Your link points to this question.